# How to configure Playwright to run tests against a different server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, playwright

I'm writing tests for playwright and running them against my local server (not written in JS, my FE is)

I was wondering though when I run these on CI, should I run them against dev or spin up a local backend?

Is there config I can use to say depending on the env you are running the tests in, choose a different server?

Is there any generic docs online about e2e tests and servers?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set this in the playwright.config file. You can set up multiple projects to dictate what values to pass through:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testinfo#test-info-config would be a start & https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browserserver may help